# OpenGL ARB function in Mac

Tags: c++, iphone, c, opengl

I want to use glCurrentPaletteMatrixARB in Mac application.
OpenGL library is imported GLEW library and GLUT and,
glewInit() function calling was successful.
glWeightPointerARB function is able to call, but my application crashed in glCurrentPaletteMatrixARB.
Reason is function pointer value is null pointer error.

Extension string is not got GL_ARB_materix_palette by glGetString.
My machine spec is MacBookPro, graphics chip is NVIDIA Geforce GT 330M.

Matrix palette can't use in Mac application in spite of the fact that iPhone simulator can use matrix palette(GL_OES_matrix_palette).
Why?

Answer (score 4):

The matrix palette extension is not widely supported and can be considered obsolete with shaders. The iPhone has this extension because it was one of the functionality Apple included for their implementation of OpenGLES1. NVidia did not. Remember, an extension means that it is optionally supported.  You cannot make assumptions that every video card will support a certain extension.

Comment: Indeed... Fixed function is behind the times. But, if matrix palette function can work in mac/windows/iPhone/ Android and so on, porting was very easy.

Comment: It served as a reference. Thanks.

Comment: It is still up to video card manufacturer to provide support for this extension for your video card.